# Unable to open Firefox and Xcode since my last update

Tags: macos, xcode, firefox, auto-update

I'm using OS X El Captain 10.11.6. It worked well until 14 Dec 2018. Indeed, I could use Firefox and Xcode (the main softwares I use) without any troubles.

But, since 14 Dec 2018, after rebooting, I can't use Firefox and Xcode anymore. For Xcode, I get this error:

```
No macOS SDK was found, but Xcode requires a macOS SDK. You may have an incomplete or damaged installation of Xcode.
```

and, for Firefox, I get this error:

```
Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.
```

I followed the Mozilla Knowledge Base, I check the `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles` folder and there are no folder in there. Has my profile disappeared?

I also noticed two Apple updates were installed on 14 Dec 2018:

- XProtectPlistConfigData (version 2101)
- MRTConfigData (version 1.38)

According to [this link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207005), MRTConfigData can delete malicious softwares and XProtectPlistConfigData can prevent their running.

Do those updates have an impact on Xcode and/or Xcode? How can I know what malicious softwares have been deleted? And how can I run Firefox and Xcode again?

Comment: I think Xcode 10 min OS requirement is [10.13.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#10.x_series).  It looks like your OS doesn't meet that req.

Comment: @fsb I'm using XCode 8.2.1 and it works well before the updates.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with your drive.  Try running First Aid in Disk Utility on your drive to see if it finds/fixes anything.

Comment: @user128998 Unfortunately, my drives appear to be OK.

Comment: @user128998 Indeed, one of my drive wasn't mounted. It contains my Firefox profile and a lot of things. It works now.